# Connected to database but JSON array is empty

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Ive tested the code and know for sure that the php code is executed however the JSON array is null.

Here is the code where the JSON is called:

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
// get JSON data from URL
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

And here is the JSONParser class:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream iStream = null;
static JSONArray jarray = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {
}

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Parse String to JSON object
    try {
        jarray = new JSONArray( builder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jarray;

}
```

}

Here is the stack trace:

```
02-20 18:33:56.640  14502-14986/com.familiestvw.whatson E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value < of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
02-20 18:33:56.680  14502-14986/com.familiestvw.whatson E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.familiestvw.whatson.GetData$ProgressTask.doInBackground(GetData.java:64)
        at com.familiestvw.whatson.GetData$ProgressTask.doInBackground(GetData.java:51)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

Neither of the catch errors are returned so i really have no idea why the JSON array is empty.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
builder.toString()
```

The response you are getting is not a valid `JSONString` so try to trace the `builder.toString()`. It can be HTML error response from server. Log the response and check what you are getting.

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value < of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

The error says it all. There is an invalid character `<` in response.

```
Log.d("JSONParser", builder.toString());
```